# Uploading file using PERN stack

Tags: reactjs, postgresql

I'm using PERN stack and while uploading the files in the UI except the xlsx file each files are getting uploaded. I have no what's going wrong. I referred a lot of things but none of them are targeting to what I'm looking for.

I'm even providing the code.

```
const data = new FormData();
        console.log("state in general =====", this.state.selectedFile);
        if (selectedFile && selectedFile.length > 0) {
          for (var x = 0; x < selectedFile.length; x++) {
            data.append("file", selectedFile[x]);
            data.append("filename[]", this.state.selectedFile[x].name);
          }
          console.log("uploaded file data", data); // this data variable is my payload in the api.
        }
```

Backend error :
[image]

Backend code :

```
await Promise.all(
    req.files.map(async file => {
      let document = await someClass.select("tableName", {
        //few parameters.
      });
      
      console.log(document);
      
      if (document.length === 0) {
        // if the file doesn't exists then only upload the new file.
        
          insert.then(doc => {
            const result = {
              status: "ok",
              filename: doc.filename,
              message: "Upload Successfully!",
            };
            messages.push(result);
          })
          .catch(err => {
            console.log("error in uploading file----------", err);
            const result = {
              status: "fail",
              filename: file.originalname,
              message: "Can NOT upload Successfully",
            };
            sendResponse(res, "Files Found", result);
          });
      } else {
        // sendResponse(res, "Files found", document);
      }
    })
  );
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What is the response code from the server you are getting. What does your network console shows?

Comment: Any error at backend for these xlsx file ?

Comment: I'm getting unhandled promise rejection in the backend code.